# Pattern Matching with Lua's string module

Tags: string, lua, find, design-patterns

I'm trying to use `string.find` in Lua to parse the contents of a user-entered string. There are up to three different parameters I am trying to find (if the user enters them), but sometimes only one.

The input string in its longer form looks like:

```
local userInput = "x|y|z"
```

where `x`, `y`, and `z` can be any character or nothing (empty string, i.e. `""`) and
`z` can also contain vertical bars/pipes - I only want to divide the string into three sections based on the first two vertical bars (`"|"`) encountered. The difficulty is that the user can also not use that form - he or she can enter simply `"x"` or `"x||z"` or `"||z"`, etc. In these case I would still need to get the values of `x`, `y`, and `z`, and it should be clear as to which variables they were assigned to.

For example, I tried this:

```
local _,_,a,b,c = string.find(usermsg, "([^|]*)|?([^|]*)|?(.+)")
```

Note first of all that this doesn't even properly fetch `a`, `b`, and `c` properly. But more importantly, when the `usermsg` was just `"x"`, it set the value of `x` to variable `c`, when it should be `a`. And when the user types `"x|y"`, variable `a` is `x` (correct) but variable `c` is `y` (wrong, it should be assigned to variable `b`).

So then I tried doing it separately:

```
local _,_,a = string.find(usermsg , "([^|]+)|?[^|]*|?.*")
local _,_,b= string.find(usermsg , "[^|]*|([^|]+)|?.*")
local _,_,c= string.find(usermsg , "[^|]*|[^|]*|(.+)")
```

But this also fails. It matches `x`, but not `y`, and `c` ends up being `y` plus the pipe and `z`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you just look for your typical split function with a max number of splits. Here is mine:

```
function string.split( str, delim, max, special )
    if max == nil then max = -1 end
    if delim == nil then delim = " " end
    if special == nil then special = False end
    local last, start, stop = 1
    local result = {}
    while max ~= 0 do
        start, stop = str:find(delim, last, not special )
        if start == nil then
            -- if max > #(all ocurances of delim in str), we end here      
            break
        end
        table.insert( result, str:sub( last, start-1 ) )
        last = stop+1
        max = max - 1
    end
    -- add the rest
    table.insert( result, str:sub( last ) )
    return result
end

print( ("A='%s' B='%s' C='%s'"):format(unpack( ("hello|there|world"):split('|', 2) )))
print( ("A='%s' B='%s' C='%s'"):format(unpack( ("||world"):split('|', 2) )))
print( ("A='%s' B='%s' C='%s'"):format(unpack( ("hello||world"):split('|', 2) )))
print( ("A='%s' B='%s' C='%s'"):format(unpack( ("hello|there|"):split('|', 2) )))
print( ("A='%s' B='%s' C='%s'"):format(unpack( ("hello||world|and|the|rest"):split('|', 2) )))
```

=>

```
A='hello' B='there' C='world'
A='' B='' C='world'
A='hello' B='' C='world'
A='hello' B='there' C=''
A='hello' B='' C='world|and|the|rest'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you intend

```
local _,_,a,b = string.find(usermsg, "([^|]*)|?(.*)")
local _,_,b,c = string.find(b, "([^|]*)|?(.*)")
```

Comment: if user input is "a|b|c" that returns
a = "a"
b = "a"
c = "|b|c"

Comment: What version of LUA are you using? I'm testing it on v5.1.4 and it is returning the intended values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this problem is `string.match`

```
local a, b, c = string.match( "(^|*)|(^|*)|(.*)" )
```

`^|` matches anything that is not `|`, and `*` means it will match 0 or more.